# Pan Gesture Animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to achieve the scrollview like animation using pan gesture.
I have achieved almost all properties of scrollview with the following code under pan gesture action method:

```
if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.changed{

        recognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: recognizer.view!.center.x, y: recognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y )

        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

    }

    if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {
        // 1
        let velocity = recognizer.velocity(in: self.view)
        let magnitude = sqrt((velocity.x * velocity.x) + (velocity.y * velocity.y))
        let slideMultiplier = magnitude / 200
        print("magnitude: \(magnitude), slideMultiplier: \(slideMultiplier)")

        // 2
        let slideFactor = 0.1 * slideMultiplier     //Increase for more of a slide
        // 3
        var finalPoint = CGPoint(x:recognizer.view!.center.x ,
                                 y:recognizer.view!.center.y + (velocity.y * slideFactor))
        // 4
        //finalPoint.x = min(max(finalPoint.x, 0), self.view.bounds.size.width)
        //finalPoint.y = min(max(finalPoint.y, 0), self.view.bounds.size.height)

        // 5
        UIView.animate(withDuration: Double(slideFactor),
                       delay: 0,
                       // 6
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut,
            animations: {recognizer.view!.center = finalPoint },
            completion: nil)
    }
```

**MY QUESTION IS:**
When pan gesture ends I have the animation to view . 
Until that animation ends my touch is not received by uiview.

I mean another pan gesture occurs only when that animation code finishes.

Is there any way my pan gesture recognizes touch before that animation is over ???

Any ideas ???

Comment: is it possible to share your code  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `allowUserInteraction` option for your animation.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: Double(slideFactor), delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseOut, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
    recognizer.view?.center = finalPoint
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: you are super angel to me , thank you very very very much :)